# How to return only one row in multilpos selects - MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

How can I limit a query inside a FROM SELECT limiting by expiration date and limit to only 1

I tried to do the example below but it didn't work.

Would anyone know how I can proceed?

Thank you very much for your attention.

```
SELECT b.*, a.siaId
FROM (
    (SELECT '02.352' AS siaId, 1 as oa from estoques order by validade asc limit 1 )
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT '05.173' AS siaId, 2 from estoques order by validade asc limit 1)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT '02.352' AS siaId, 3 from estoques order by validade asc limit 1)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT '05.173' AS siaId, 4 from estoques order by validade asc limit 1)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT '05.451' AS siaId, 5 from estoques order by validade asc limit 1)
) AS a
LEFT JOIN estoques AS b USING (siaId)
order by a.oa
```

Current results

```
[
{siaId:'02.352', validade: '2023-05-05' ...},
{siaId:'02.352', validade: '2023-06-05' ...},
{null},
{siaId:'02.652', validade: '2023-07-05' ...},
{null},
{siaId:'05.451', validade: '2023-07-06' ...},
{siaId:'05.451', validade: '2023-07-08' ...},
]
```

Expected outcome

```
[
    {siaId:'02.352', validade: '2023-05-05' ...},
    {null},
    {siaId:'02.652', validade: '2023-07-05' ...},
    {null},
    {siaId:'05.451', validade: '2023-07-06' ...}
    ]
```

The query works, just the filter by validity and by limit does not work.

There is more than one record by sia_id

Comment: Why did you expect that query to return only one row?

Comment: The query works, just the filter by validity and by limit does not work.

There is more than one record by sia_id

Comment: The limit works fine, you're unioning 5 queries, each limited to one row. So you get 5 rows. You're asking how to get the most recent date within a group, which is probably one of the most often asked sql related questions on SO

Comment: I edited. Includes the error shown.

Comment: If "The query works", why did you post an error?

Comment: Pardon. Query works without order by and limit filters

Comment: When I add the Order By and Limit the error is shown

Comment: `SELECT '05.173' AS siagre_id` isn't in the posted query. Honestly, the query doesn't make much sense. The queries you are unioning only select hard-coded values, with no relation to the table you're selecting from. And you join those rows based on those hard-coded values. You need to explain what you are actually trying to do, and what data you have

Comment: why don't you use "IN" operation instead of using subquery?

Comment: Order must remain. Including null rows.

Comment: HoneyBadger . how ?

Comment: maybe you have to provide us more specific table structure

Comment: Hi, what for example? the only lookup columns are siaId and validade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT min(b.validade) as validade, a.siaId
FROM (
    SELECT '02.352' AS siaId, 1 as oa from estoques order by validade asc limit 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '05.173' AS siaId, 2 from estoques order by validade asc limit 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '02.652' AS siaId, 3 from estoques order by validade asc limit 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '05.173' AS siaId, 4 from estoques order by validade asc limit 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '05.451' AS siaId, 5 from estoques order by validade asc limit 1
) AS a
LEFT JOIN estoques AS b
    USING (siaId)
group by b.siaId
order by a.oa
```

To prevent query returning duplicate data you can use "DISTINCT".
But the problem is your data is not duplicate

```
{siaId:'02.352', validade: '2023-05-05' ...},
{siaId:'02.352', validade: '2023-06-05' ...},
```

You have to make decision what do you want the query return!
if you want the older data so you can use "MIN" function on validade column and ends up with group by siaId

Comment: Order must remain. Including null rows.

Comment: if you still need those subquery to returning null rows, so just specify what validade you decide the oldest or newest

Comment: I need that, when I have duplicate data with the same siaId, the validade will be different